# How to exit from the scanner.hasNextLine() loop in java

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I want to read the following input (as a single stream) from the terminal which contains multiple lines.

```
INSERT KEY adam key
TURN KEY adam
ENTER HOUSE adam
INSERT KEY pat foobar
TURN KEY pat
ENTER HOUSE pat
WHO'S INSIDE?
```

I'm using the following code to read them and add to an Array List.

```
 ArrayList<String> instructions_list = new ArrayList<String>();
 String input_line = "";
 while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
     input_line = sc.nextLine();
     instructions_list.add(input_line);
     System.out.println(input_line);
 }

System.out.println("Outside Loop");
```

This prints line by line correctly. But it seems it doesn't go outside the while loop. How can I exit the while loop and run the next code lines?

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Type Ctrl/d or Ctrl/z at the console, depending on your operating system.

Comment: How do you enter text containing newline characters at the console? Don't you have to enter a single line and then press the _ENTER_ key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide an exit condition where the loop should terminate i.e. after taking some fixed number of lines or after encountering some specific word etc

or you can try :

```
ArrayList<String> instructions_list = new ArrayList<String>();
 String input_line = "";
 while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
     input_line = sc.nextLine();
     if(input_line.equals(""))
        break;
     instructions_list.add(input_line);
     System.out.println(input_line);
```

When a blank line will be encountered the loop will terminate